# Passwordless authentication flow using Cognito & API Gateway & Lambda (Python)

Tags: python, api, boto3, amazon-cognito, password-less

I've been trying to implement passwordless authentication using AWS Cognito & API Gateway & Lambda (Python)

I have followed these articles:
https://medium.com/digicred/password-less-authentication-in-cognito-cafa016d4db7
https://medium.com/@pjatocheseminario/passwordless-api-using-cognito-and-serverless-framework-7fa952191352

I have configured Cognito (to accept CUSTOM_AUTH), added the Lambdas, and created the API endpoints:

```
/sign-up 
/initiate-auth (aka initiate login)
/respond-to-auth-challenge (aka (verify login)
```

When calling initiateAuth I receive the following response:
An error occurred (NotAuthorizedException) when calling the InitiateAuth operation: Incorrect username or password."

I'm using CUSTOM_AUTH which doesn't require password, and the user name is definitely correct because it actually initiates the authentication flow and I receive a code, however because boto3 doesn't respond with a session I can't continue the authentication.

This is how I call Cognito:

```
res = cognito.initiate_auth(
        ClientId=client_id,
        AuthFlow="CUSTOM_AUTH",
        AuthParameters={
            "USERNAME": email,
            "PASSWORD": random_password  
            }
        )
```

It's probably something small I'm missing but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same error, and I think that the error message is misleading.
When you did not respond correctly in Create-Auth-Challenge lambda, you will get this error. So make sure everything is right in your lambda.

Answer (score 6):

Your client code looks OK, mine has `ClientId` param in it but if your code is not raising an exception then it should be fine. Unless you had `Generate client secret` option checked when you created your app client.
If that is the case then you have to pass in `SECRET_HASH` in `AuthParameters` like the following:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

def get_secret_hash(email, client_id, client_secret):                                                                   
     """                                                                                                                 
     A keyed-hash message authentication code (HMAC) calculated using                                                    
     the secret key of a user pool client and username plus the client                                                   
     ID in the message.                                                                                                  
     """                                                                                                                 
     message = email + client_id                                                                                         
     client_secret = str.encode(client_secret)                                                                           
     dig = hmac.new(client_secret, msg=message.encode('UTF-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()                       
     return base64.b64encode(dig).decode()
                                                                                                                 
client.admin_initiate_auth(                                                                                  
    UserPoolId=COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,                                                                                    
    ClientId=CLIENT_ID,                                                                                                 
    AuthFlow='CUSTOM_AUTH',                                                                                             
    AuthParameters={                                                                                                    
        'USERNAME': email,                                                                                              
        'SECRET_HASH': get_secret_hash(email, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET) # Omit if secret key option is disabled.                                                          
    },
)
```

Next, double check the following:

Under `App clients > * > Auth Flows Configuration`, is `ALLOW_CUSTOM_AUTH` option enabled for your client?

Under `App integration > App client settings > * > Enabled Identity Providers`, is your user pool selected?

If you have Cognito setup correctly and your code still doesn't work then it is probably the lambda code. You probably know this but for password-less custom auth you need to use 3 lambda triggers: `Define Auth Challenge`, `Create Auth Challenge`, and `Verify Auth Challenge`.

Custom auth lambdas events are triggered in the following order:

1. DefineAuthChallenge_Authentication:

   - Technically, issueTokens can be set to True here to return tokens without going through the rest of the steps.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if event['triggerSource'] == 'DefineAuthChallenge_Authentication':
        event['response']['challengeName'] = 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE'
        event['response']['issueTokens'] = False
        event['response']['failAuthentication'] = False

        if event['request']['session']:  # Needed for step 4.
            # If all of the challenges are answered, issue tokens.
            event['response']['issueTokens'] = all(
                answered_challenge['challengeResult'] for answered_challenge in event['request']['session'])
    return event
```

2. CreateAuthChallenge_Authentication:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if event['triggerSource'] == 'CreateAuthChallenge_Authentication':
        if event['request']['challengeName'] == 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE':
            event['response']['privateChallengeParameters'] = {}
            event['response']['privateChallengeParameters']['answer'] = 'YOUR CHALLENGE ANSWER HERE'
            event['response']['challengeMetadata'] = 'AUTHENTICATE_AS_CHALLENGE'
    return event
```

Then your client must respond to the challenge:

```
client.respond_to_auth_challenge(                                                                            
    ClientId=CLIENT_ID,                                                                                                 
    ChallengeName='CUSTOM_CHALLENGE',                                                                                   
    Session=session,                                                                                                    
    ChallengeResponses={                                                                                                
        'USERNAME': email,                                                                                              
        'ANSWER': 'Extra Protection!',                                                                                  
        'SECRET_HASH': get_secret_hash(email, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)  # Omit if secret key option is disabled.                                                 
    }                                                                                                                   
)
```

3. VerifyAuthChallengeResponse_Authentication:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if event['triggerSource'] == 'VerifyAuthChallengeResponse_Authentication':
        if event['request']['challengeAnswer'] == event['request']['privateChallengeParameters']['answer']:
            event['response']['answerCorrect'] = True
    return event
```

4. DefineAuthChallenge_Authentication:

   - Set `event['response']['issueTokens']` to `True` to return tokens (code shown in step 1), or issue another challenge to keep repeating steps 1-3.

Finally, make sure that if case-insensitivity option is enabled for your user pool too. Also, I can't exactly recall if `CUSTOM_AUTH` flow worked if the user is in `FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD` status. If the user is in that state, then try settings a permanent password with the sdk to set the status to `CONFIRMED`.

Comment: If the user is in FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD status it does not work. But your example was very good, I implemented it and is working fine.